# Cannot get Axis example to run

Tags: java, axis

I am trying to run the Axis "getting started" example code from here:

http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#BasicsGettingStarted

Other than adding a missing quote on line 15 it is the same code with some added logging.  I get this error:

```
Transport is org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPTransport@4c6aacbf
Set target endpoint address
Set operation name
Enter: Call::invoke(ns, meth, args)
operation=null
Failed to set EntityResolver to null on DocumentBuilder
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.ChainingEntityResolver.popEntityResolver(ChainingEntityResolver.java:75)
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryDocumentBuilder.setEntityResolver(RegistryDocumentBuilder.java:179)
```

Any ideas?  I saw that there was a similar question but without an answer.  I am using Axis 1.3 and Weblogic 9.2.3.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that strikes me is that the URL:

http://ws.apache.org:5049/axis/services/echo

does not seem to be available. Can you try another?

Comment: Well, I tried to use a local service but I got the same result.  Also, does it throw an exception just because the service is down?